# Printing output from JavaScript into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, output

first time posting here, so go easy on me please! I am in an intro to JavaScript class and we are working on making a webpage that updates with the time that has passed since the Unix Epoch. This includes milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days and years. I am having a hard time getting my JavaScript to output into my HTML page.

Here is the  of my HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my Time Calculator</h1>
    <main>
        <p>Below is the time that has elapsed since the
            Unix Epoch: 1/1/1970 at midnight. Hit refresh
            to update the calculation.</p>
        <div>
            <label>Milliseconds</label>
            <span id="millis"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Seconds</label>
            <span id="seconds"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Minutes</label>
            <span id="minutes"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Hours</label>
            <span id="hours"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Days</label>
            <span id="days"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Years</label>
            <span id="years"></span>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="scripts/time.js"></script>
</body>`
```

Here is my JS:

```
let millis = new Date().getTime;
let millisInSeconds = millis / 1000;
let secondsInMinutes =  millisInSeconds * 60;
let minutesInHours = secondsInMinutes * 60;
let hoursInDays = minutesInHours * 24;
let daysInYears = hoursInDays * 365;

millis = parseFloat(millis);
millisInSeconds = parseFloat(millisInSeconds);
secondsInMinutes = parseFloat(secondsInMinutes);
minutesInHours = parseFloat(minutesInHours);
hoursInDays = parseFloat(hoursInDays);
daysInYears = parseFloat(daysInYears);

const millisDoc = document.querySelector("#millis").innerHTML = millis;
const secondsDoc = document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = millisInSeconds;
const minutesDoc = document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = secondsInMinutes;
const hoursDoc = document.querySelector("#hours").innerHTML = minutesInHours;
const daysDoc = document.querySelector("#days").innerHTML = hoursInDays;
const yearsDoc = document.querySelector("#years").innerHTML = daysInYears;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues in your logic:

- `getTime` is a method so you need to include `()` to invoke it: `new Date().getTime()`
- The `const xDoc =` assignments are redundant in this case and should be removed.
- The seconds, minutes, hours and days values are derived by dividing the previous value, not multiplying.

Here's working example with those corrections made:

```js
let millis = new Date().getTime();
let millisInSeconds = millis / 1000;
let secondsInMinutes = millisInSeconds / 60;
let minutesInHours = secondsInMinutes / 60;
let hoursInDays = minutesInHours / 24;
let daysInYears = hoursInDays / 365;

millis = parseFloat(millis);
millisInSeconds = parseFloat(millisInSeconds);
secondsInMinutes = parseFloat(secondsInMinutes);
minutesInHours = parseFloat(minutesInHours);
hoursInDays = parseFloat(hoursInDays);
daysInYears = parseFloat(daysInYears);

document.querySelector("#millis").innerHTML = millis;
document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = millisInSeconds;
document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = secondsInMinutes;
document.querySelector("#hours").innerHTML = minutesInHours;
document.querySelector("#days").innerHTML = hoursInDays;
document.querySelector("#years").innerHTML = daysInYears;
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Below is the time that has elapsed since the Unix Epoch: 1/1/1970 at midnight. Hit refresh to update the calculation.</p>
  <div>
    <label>Milliseconds</label>
    <span id="millis"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Seconds</label>
    <span id="seconds"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Minutes</label>
    <span id="minutes"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Hours</label>
    <span id="hours"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Days</label>
    <span id="days"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Years</label>
    <span id="years"></span>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: you are my savior! such a simple thing that got left out. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Give class tutor Rory an apple.